# Align x tick labels to be left justified - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have long tick labels on the x axis, they are rotated, I would like the text to align to the bottom (it would be the left if they were not rotated) I have tried different combinations of ha, and va, but I can not get what I would like - Here is an image of the current plot, and the code:

```
    title = data[0][1]
    subtitle = data[0][2]

    column_A = 0
    column_B = 1
    columns = [column_A, column_B]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    for sub_data, col in zip(data, columns):
        df[col] = sub_data[4:]

    # converts str to int
    df[column_B] = df[column_B].replace('[\\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

    asin_title = df[column_A]
    revenue = df[column_B]

    # deconstruct fig and ax - this needs to be done before creating the histogram
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4), linewidth=1, edgecolor=gray)

    # format y ticks, insert comma
    # fmtr = StrMethodFormatter(('${x:,g}'))
    # ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmtr)

    # Removes the spines
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

    # set the x limit
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 30)

    # create histogram using asin_title and revenue
    plt.bar(asin_title, height=revenue, color=bar_blue,)

    ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())

    ax.set_xticklabels(asin_title)
    labels = ['\n'.join(wrap(title[:30] + '..', 22)) for title in asin_title]

    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation='vertical', fontsize=6)
    
    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[10:]:
        label.set_visible(False)


    # for tick in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    #     tick.set_horizontalalignment("left")

    # create space from top of chart
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.13)

    # title, subtitle
    plt.title(title, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', ha='left',
              color=dark_gray, pad=30, x=-0.04, y=0.98)
    # use text() for subtitle with transform=ax.transAxes so matching x offsets line up
    plt.text(-0.04, 1.11, subtitle, fontsize=8, fontweight='bold',
             ha='left', transform=ax.transAxes, color=gray)

    # y ticks
    plt.yticks(fontsize=8)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)

    # show lines on the y ticks
    plt.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='y')

    # set tight_layout
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('top_asins.png')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that each label has centered text but both text center and axis distance differ among labels?

Comment: I think so. The labels are two lines that wrap. The first line is an ID starting with B, I would like the Bs to line up (again, if they were not rotated they would be left aligned,) and the second line to line up with the start of the first line.